# Compiler not throwing "Cannot find module" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

In my project I have 2 files:

**foo.js**

`const image = require('../this/path/is/wrong.png');`

**boo.tsx**

`const image = require('../this/path/is/wrong.png');`

In **foo.js** TypeScript correctly finds out that the image does not exists and throws "Cannot find module" error, but no error is thrown for **boo.tsx** so the bug only shows up on runtime when the app crashes.

If I just rename **boo.tsx** to **boo.js** TS again starts throwing the error as expected.

Those are some of my compiler options that I think could be relevant:

```
"module":"es2015",
"target": "es2015",
"jsx": "react",
"moduleResolution":"Node",
"allowJs": true,
```

I've tried:

- different module and moduleResolution settings
- using import instead of require
- with and without `@types/node`

Is there any special `tsconfig` settings I am missing or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you try `boo.ts`?

Comment: @DevanBuggay No change :(

Comment: What happens if you try module=ES5, target=ES5 and moduleResolution="Node"?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you declared any `include` and `exclude` of `files` types in tsconfig.json? If so can you check whether your project includes the .png file formats. Never mind if the setup is good.

Comment: I assume both files are at the  level in same folder structure.

Comment: None of the suggestions above helped :(

Answer (score 2):

The `require` function has no special meaning in a `.ts` or `.tsx` file, since TypeScript only uses recognizes syntax for imports.

In a `.js` file with `allowJs`, it is uses heuristics, and recognizes the `require` call as an import.

The more equivalent thing for TypeScript would be something like

```
import image = require('../this/path/is/wrong.png');
```

or one of the ES module syntaxes such as

```
import * as foo from "foo";

import foo from "foo";
```

Comment: I don't understand why it recognizes require in JS files but not in TS files. 

When I try the `import image = require()` syntax I get an error:

`Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.`

Comment: Amended my response to use ES module syntax in certain cases.

Comment: This won't help either. I've mentioned in the question that i've tried import instead of require. It will always show the module as missing unless you add a declaration for that file which in turn will make it again never show the error as with require.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to your `tsconfig`

Comment: Nope, it was always enabled.